# Getting two different words as part of in a regular expression

Tags: regex

Getting two different words as part of in a regular expression

I want to catch say

"This Text" and "This Somethingelse"

I currently have

```
\s*This\sText.*
```

but I am trying to catch both "Text" and "Somethingelse"

I am somewhat new to regular expressions but have looked at this and am stumped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this...

```
\s*This\s(Text|SomethingElse).*
```

If you are using PHP, you can find out if it was `Text` or `SomethingElse` like so...

```
if (preg_match('/\s*This\s(Text|SomethingElse).*/', $text, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[1];
    // $result will now be either "text" or "SomethingElse"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A sequence of "word" characters can be represented as

```
\w+
```

in most regex dialects.